# Change video file container to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I have learned through Google, that to change video containers without losing quality I can run the following command:

ffmpeg -i videofile.mkv -codec copy videofile.mp4

This has worked great for a number of video files I have.  However, I am having an issue with three of them (1 mkv file and 2 avi files).  When I run that command against them, the video is there, but there is no sound.  There is sound in the original video file.

Any ideas how to put the video in a new container while retaining the audio track?

Thanks.  Brian

Comment: Share full log. Generate log using `ffmpeg -i videofile.mkv -codec copy videofile.mp4 2> log.txt`

Answer (score 2):

The .mp4 container is not compatible with the **audio** codecs of the problem files.  This should be evident from the logs.  So the audio channels of the problem files have to be transcoded to something allowed in .mp4, eg. aac:

```
ffmpeg  -i videofile.mkv -c:v copy -c:a aac videofile.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the container `mp4` it doesn’t compatible whith codec of your input video `mkv` and `avi`

By the way, you can try

`ffmpeg  -i videofile.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy videofile.mp4`

Check this documentation.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_codecs
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map

Comment: Your command is the same as the asker's. Only difference is that data and subtitle streams, if any, will be transcoded.